# Views Preview Shows Results, but Browsing the Path Doesn't

Tags: views

My site is running Drupal 8.9.3 with "Views taxonomy term name into ID" 8.x-1.0-alpha3 and "Hierarchical Taxonomy Menu" 8.x-1.x-dev.

I'm trying to create a view that shows Drupal Commerce products tagged with terms from a particular vocabulary. When editing the view, the preview shows the results I expect:

[image: View Preview]

The problem is that I don't see these results when I view that path directly from my browser. The path resolves, but there's no content displayed:

[image: View Path]

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Are you logged in with the same account/have permissions when checking both the views UI and view page?

Comment: Yes, same session, same (admin) account.

Comment: I see you have a contextual filter, is your view a block? If so in your contextual filter what have you said when the contextual filter doesn't exist? You should select it to use the relevant path variable

Comment: This is a page view.

Comment: and what have you got set for your contextual filter if its not found?

Comment: `This is a page view.` Wait a minute, how come there is an edit button then? [Looks like a node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G0qb.png) to me.

Comment: "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL" is set to "Display all results for the specified field". I've tried other valves with no change in the result.

Comment: > Looks like a node to me. Clicking that edit button takes me to the form to edit the taxonomy term.

Comment: A-ha! I think I found the problem. The path for my page view is the same as the path for the taxonomy term. When I change the path in the view, I get the results I expect when I view the page. However, this leads to a different issue: I'd like the taxonomy term menu items to show me the products that are tagged with the term. Is creating a view not the right way to do this?